# Alexa - trying to compare intent "f150", the Ford truck model to the written "f150"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have tried removing non-alphanumeric characters and spacing out the numbers to match common vernacular "f 1 50". I have verified that Alexa service is returning the intent in numeric form (as it is in the utterances).

What am I missing or what issue am I running into that is causing the intent not to match the string?

Answer (score 0):

The trick with Alexa is to never have letters and numbers together and any single letters must be followed by a period.

So the truck model "f150" must be entered as "f. 1 50"